# jQuery clone 2 menus but appended 2nd menu does not get mmenu classes added

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I have 2 seperate menus i am trying to clone into one mmenu for mobile. I am trying to apend the second one to the mmenu but it is not getting the styles applied when mmenu clones the ul with child ul and li's.

My menu look like this

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Menu 1
        <ul>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Menu 1
        <ul>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Menu 1
        <ul>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav id="menuB">  
    <ul>
      <li>Menu 1
        <ul>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Menu 1
        <ul>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Menu 1
        <ul>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

and my jquery looks like this for appending the menuB to the mmenu

```
$("#menu").mmenu({
    // options
}, {
    // configuration
clone: true
});
$('#mm-menu ul').append($('#menuB ul').html());
```

The appended menuB menu 1 items lok ok but the sub menu or menu2 items are not getting the mmenu classes and styles applied and look like plain bulleted lists.

Anyone ideas how to append after mmenu has cloned the menu and then add the classes like it does for the first menu?

https://jsfiddle.net/abennington/3vyqyh9j/8/

Comment: i have tried to setup a fiddle but cant seem to get styles to show correctly but it does show how the second menu sub menu items are bulleted lists https://jsfiddle.net/abennington/3vyqyh9j/7/

Comment: ok got is styled correct and now you can see my problem in all its glory :) 

https://jsfiddle.net/abennington/3vyqyh9j/8/

Comment: Can't you just append the second menu before initializing the plugin? https://jsfiddle.net/h8o2ao4h/

Comment: no if you drag the window larger it appends it to the desktop version or left side menu. For a second i got excited because it seemed to work but drag the results frame larger to see yours is appended to the dektop menu and not only the mmenu :)

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/3vyqyh9j/21/

Comment: it does not look like it is appending the menu B to the the first menu :)